# Issue sending json array via ajax to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I'm sending via AJAX to my server nodejs, with this JS on client side:

```
function login(){
    var array=[];
    var jsonData={};
    jsonData.user=$('#user').val();
    jsonData.pass=$('#pass').val();
    array.push(jsonData);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST', 
        url: 'auth',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(array)
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
}
```

As can you see, before send ajax, the browser output console is:

```
[{"user":"User001","pass":"SecretPassword"}]
```

On server side, I have this code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body); 
    // { '[{"user":"User001","pass":"SecretPassword"}]': '' }

    console.log(JSON.parse(req.body));   
    // {"[{\"user\":\"User001\",\"pass\":\"SecretPassword\"}]":""}


    res.sendStatus(202);
}
```

But, if I test this web service with Postman, my server receives Json data correctly:
[Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouUzS.png)

Please, does anyone help me??, I trying solve this about 2 days :(

Comment: You should set the content type to json if that's what you are sending

Comment: Yes, it is. Please see the first code fragment:
dataType: 'application/json',

Comment: That is not the content type,  dataType is something else

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't stringify data, it's supposed to be an object, so you can send jsonData directly:

```
function login(){
    var array=[];
    var jsonData={};
    jsonData.user=$('#user').val();
    jsonData.pass=$('#pass').val();
    array.push(jsonData);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST', 
        url: 'auth',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: jsonData // << here
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
}
```

Comment: Nope, I tried that and can't solve the problem. The answer is this: contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' in the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

var invoiceJson = {name: "abc"};

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(invoicejson),
    success: (data) => {
        try {
            console.log( data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log( err);
        }
    }
})
```